# Finding the number of occurences of an integer in multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

I wish to find the number of occurrences of a number taken as input in the given multidimensional array defined by the logic below:

```
...
int n,x,count=0;
cin>> n >> x;
 int a[n][n]  ;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]= i*j ;
    }
}
   for( int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for( int j=1;j<=n;j++)

    {
        if(a[i][j] == x)
            ++count;
    }
}
  cout<< count ;
...
```

For eg., if I give input as 6(`n`) and 12(to find its number of occurrences, `x` here). The multidimensional array looks something like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  
2  4  6  8 10 12  
3  6  9 12 15 18  
4  8 12 16 20 24  
5 10 15 20 25 30  
6 12 18 24 30 36
```

Now, the number of occurences of 12 here is 4(count).
But when I give `n` as 10 and `x` as 5, the program stops working. I can't seem to find what is happening. Can someone help me on this?
Also in what way can I modify my code?
How can I handle the case when `n` is as large as 1000 or 10k without changing the logic of the program?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You dont show the code that contains the error, but only how you fill the array

Comment: You have only shown half the code, where is the find the number code?

Comment: I have edited it now. Thank you.

Comment: `int a[n][n]  ;` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ cannot use variables to denote the number of entries.

Comment: Example -- [Doesn't compile here](http://rextester.com/RLHN99384).

Comment: BTW, to solve the problem, you don't need to create the array.

Comment: @Jarod42 There are other ways. what you got?

Comment: I mean simply `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        if (i * j == x) { ++count;}
    }
}`

Comment: And from that, you can even do `for (int i=1;i <= n;i++) { if ((x / i) * i == x && (x / i) <= n) {++count;} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Indices in C/C++ starts at `0`**. If an array is declared to have size `n` as in `int a[n]` the only valid indices are: `0,1,...,n-1`  i.e. `[0,n[`

If you go out of bound undefined behaviour is expected. That should be your case.

**Fix the loops as follows (note the new bounds and the `+1` in `i` and `j`)**

```
 int a[n][n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        a[i][j]= (i+1)*(j+1) ;
```

Comment: If i initialise it with zero, the first row and column will be zero.

Comment: @The_sinner  use `a[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1)` then. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Worked. @Davide Spataro

Comment: That array is not a valid array in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why is not? Cause `n` is not `const`?

Comment: @DavideSpataro -- Because it isn't a valid array.  An array in C++ must use constant expressions to denote the number of entries.  You're using an extension provided by your compiler called `Variable Length Arrays` or VLA.  Regardless, it is still not valid C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I know, I thought you were referring to something else I was not able to see.  To be precise, `clang` and `icpc` supports  VLAs too. That was not the core of the problem in this case ;)

Comment: How can i handle the case when n is as large as 1000 or 10k? @Davide Spataro

Comment: You better use dynamic memory for that. Not that when `n=10k` `a` is quite large as contains `n^2 = 100000000` integers

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    count += std::count(a[i], a[i] + n, x);
}
```

or a more simpler version:

```
std::cout << std::count(a[0], a[0] + n*n, x);
```

Comment: One more remark: the variable 'a' is declared twice. Please correct it.